# Awk: count all space up to second column as a single variable?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
This is the first line    80 55 75%
Second line               25 95 74%  
The next line             50 50 50%
```

As you can see, on the left side the number of words will vary. Currently, if I use a command like this:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

This works out great for the first line and will return:

```
This is the first line
```

But if I do this on the second line:

```
awk 'NR == 2 {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

I get this, as expected:

```
Second line 25 95
```

But this is not what I need. For scripting purposes, I need awk, or perhaps another tool to "see" anything up to the second column of numbers as a single variable. So regardless of the number of words on the left side, they will always be seen as a single variable. How can I achieve this?

NOTE: I may have lines like this:

```
This is a testmarket001    65 45 25%
```

So I don't think you can just tell awk to print all words up to the first number, as it would cut off part of the line.

Comment: do you happen to have tabs in between columns? This would life way easier.

Comment: Will you have only 3 col.s of numbers at the end? Another way to make life easy :)

Comment: why not just select [a-z][A-Z] only from the whole line?

Comment: The file is generated with the paste command, and yes, I think it does implement tabs. #paste file1 file 2 file 3 | column -s $'\t' -t > /home/user/file.

Comment: Fazlin - yes there will always be 3 colums of numbers at the end. That will always be static.

Comment: `awk 'NF-=3' file` ?

Comment: `awk '{print substr($0,1,26)}' file` ?

Comment: 123 - OK I like the simplicity here. But how would I then print each set of numbers separately?

Comment: 123 Disregard - I can still use regular string matching with awk on that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 3 whitespace separates words at the end of each line you can use this `awk` to get your output:

```
awk '{gsub(/(\s+\S+){3}\s*$/, "")} 1' file

This is the first line
Second line
The next line
```

You may also use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(\s+\S+){3}\s*$//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your fields are tab delimited, just set the delimiter for `awk`

```
$ paste file1 file2 file3 | awk -F'\t' '{print $1}'
```

should work.

Note that `column` command modifies the tabs.  If your file is saved after `column` formatting, you can try this

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF-2;i++) printf "%s ",$i; print ""}' file

This is the first line
Second line
The next line
```